# Testcontainers Kafka containers throw NoClassDefFoundError: DockerException in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, testcontainers

I am trying to setup a kafka containers using Testcontainers. However, it throw me an exception: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/dockerjava/api/exception/DockerException` at this line:

```
 @Container
  public static KafkaContainer kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1"));
```

Here is the whole log:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/dockerjava/api/exception/DockerException

    at com.project.api.kafka.HelloKafkaListenerTestIT.<clinit>(HelloKafkaListenerTestIT.java:38)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:250)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:260)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$2.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.DockerException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 29 more
```

Here is my test class:

```
@Testcontainers
@SpringBootTest
public class HelloKafkaListenerTestIT {
  
  @Container
  public static KafkaContainer kafkaContainer = new KafkaContainer(DockerImageName.parse("confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.1"));
  
  @MockBean
  private HelloKafkaService helloKafkaService;
  
  @Autowired
  private HelloKafkaProducer helloKafkaProducer;
  
  @DynamicPropertySource
  static void kafkaProperties(DynamicPropertyRegistry registry) {
    registry.add(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaContainer::getBootstrapServers);
    registry.add(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, () -> "test-id");
    registry.add(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, () -> LongSerializer.class.getName());
    registry.add(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, () -> StringSerializer.class.getName());
  }
  
  @Test
  public void helloKafkaListenerTest() {
    ArgumentCaptor<ExampleEvent> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ExampleEvent.class);
    ExampleEvent exampleEvent = new ExampleEvent("Hello World");
    helloKafkaProducer.writeToKafka(exampleEvent);
    verify(helloKafkaService, timeout(5000)).handleMessage(captor.capture());
    assertNotNull(captor.getValue());
    assertEquals("Hello World", captor.getValue().getExampleField());
  }
  
}
```

Here is my maven :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.6</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
    <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
    <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
    <version>5.12.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Anyone knows why this happens? Thank you

Comment: Can you share a minimal example which reproduces the problem in a github repository?

Comment: Thank you. I just tried and it looks like some dependencies could not be installed correctly. Now, it's working.